# How to set proxy_pass https in nginx ingress Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to create a rule to forward https request to an https backend with an Kubernetes ngnix ingress controller. So far I was not able to create a working rule. I've tried several ingress statements in my k8s manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hs-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
#    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
#    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
#    ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
#    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  namespace: heartbleed-test
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /banana
          backend:
            serviceName: hs-service
            servicePort: 443
```

After some digging I figured out that the problem is the proxy_pass property in the ingress rule on the controller:

```
proxy_pass: http://heartbleed-test-hs-service-443;
```

When i change http to https everything works as expected.
So how do I set this property from my k8s manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol
```

... solved my problem

Comment: Thanks for posting your fix, it resolved my problem too!